# Correct formatting to send a list in Python as a parameter to the Google Web App in order to send the data to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Python code in which I want to pass a DataFrame Pandas as a parameter and a URL also as a parameter in my request to the Web App of Google Apps Script:

```python
import pandas as pd
import requests

UAGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': UAGENT
    }

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': [1,2,3,4,5],'Col B': ['A','B','C','D','E']})
df_list = df.values.tolist()

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXX/exec"
params = {
    'pylist': df_list,
    'okgo': url
}
web_app_response = requests.get(
    webAppsUrl, headers=headers, params=params, timeout=360
)
```

In my Web App code I tried to send it to the spreadsheet like this:

```javascript
function doGet(e) {
    var pylist = e.parameter.pylist;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All Python');
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, pylist.length, pylist[0].length).setValues(pylist);
```

My expected result in Google Sheets `All Python` page:

| 1 | A |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

But I received a `Bad Request Error 400` when making the request.

In this case, what is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I cannot know your expected result. But, I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that `e.parameter.pylist` is an object. When your python request is used, `e.parameter.pylist` is `{"okgo":"###","pylist":"###"}`. When this value is used for `setValues(pylist)`, an error like `The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.` occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to put the values without the error, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `doGet` is modified as follows.

##### From:

```
var pylist = e.parameter.pylist;
```

##### To:

```
var header = ['pylist', 'okgo'];
var pylist = [header, header.map(h => e.parameters[h].join(","))];
```

or, if you want to put both keys and values in the row, how about the following modification?

```
var pylist = Object.entries(e.parameters).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.join(",")]);
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### Added:

From your updated question, the reason for your current issue is due to that `e.parameter.pylist` is an object. So, how about the following modification? In this modification, `df_list` is sent as a string.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify as follows.

##### From:

```js
var pylist = e.parameter.pylist;
```

##### To:

```js
var pylist = JSON.parse(e.parameter.pylist);
```

#### Python script:

Please modify as follows.

##### From:

```py
params = {
    'pylist': df_list,
    'okgo': url
}
```

##### To:

Please include `import json`.

```py
params = {"pylist": json.dumps(df_list), "okgo": url}
```

Comment: Hello @Tanaike ! I'm going to rephrase the question because the way I explained it gave more than one way of interpreting it, my mistake. I'll edit and let you know my real need!

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand your reply. About `Hello @Tanaike ! I'm going to rephrase the question because the way I explained it gave more than one way of interpreting it, my mistake. I'll edit and let you know my real need!`, your question is different from your actual question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When I read your answer I realized that my question was not as clear as I thought. I'm editing it to make it easier to understand!

Comment: Done @Tanaike , I edited the question and included my expected result!

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying. About your updated question, I added the modification point in my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: After testing, I realize that the values are even placed in the spreadsheet but instead of completing the code execution, it generates the same error. I added in the question the original list I'm trying to send and also put in more detail the error I get from the request response.

Comment: I don't know where the error could be, because if I use the original list and try to create a Dataframe with it, it works perfectly. If there were any errors, Pandas would raise an error.

Comment: I also added a GIF to the question where it shows that the request response generates an error even when the values are inserted in the spreadsheet

Comment: I've also just added my complete Web App script to make it easier if you want to do a full test run!

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying. First, please don't change your question. I was surprised that you had changed your same question 3 times. I think that the reason for the current issue with your latest script is the length of the query parameter. In your 3rd script, I'm worried that the size of the query parameter is more than 2 kbytes in the maximum size. But, it seems that in the current stage, even when the size of the query parameter is more than 2 kbytes, the data is sent although an error is returned.

Comment: @Digital Farmer So, when my proposed modification is reflected in your script, the sent value is correctly put into the Spreadsheet. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification. I apologize for my poor skill. On the other hand, In your 2nd script, you use `df = pd.DataFrame({"Col A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Col B": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})`. In this case, the size of the query parameter is less than 2 kbytes. By this, no error occurs. I think that the reason for your current issue is this. In this case, how about using `doPost`?

Comment: I change Python to ```request.post``` and GAS to ```function doPost(e) {``` but unfortunately the error persists

Comment: Sorry for updating the question, I wanted to create something more complete but forgot StackOverflow's rules about edits after there are already answers.

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying. About `I change Python to request.post and GAS to function doPost(e) { but unfortunately the error persists`, do you want to change your question again? I would like to correctly understand your actual question. I apologize that I cannot know your actual question. About `I wanted to create something more complete but forgot StackOverflow's rules about edits after there are already answers.`, I deeply apologize that I posted my answer before you update your question.

Comment: I've returned the question to the answer version because it fixed the initial issue and I'm going to create a new question with the current need.